# Drupal 6 Hide Revision Information

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, formbuilder

I'm trying to hide "Revision information" from my users who do not understand what that is in relation to this content type. I've read numerous posts online that suggest anything from changing a template to setting style="display: none". I'd prefer to actually remove the field from access so that injection techniques aren't still viable. I've done this by creating a 
`hook_form_alter` that sets `$form['revision_information']['#access'] = false;`. I've verified with Firebug that the method is indeed called, yet the form elements prevail. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance! Drupal rocks!

```
function recipe_form_recipe_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state){
    if (isset($form['revision_information'])) {
        $form['revision_information']['#access'] = FALSE;
        firep(print_r($form['revision_information'],true));
        $form_state['rebuild'] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you pass $form by reference?

Comment: It's strange that your form_alter does not work, since the forms api documentation and may posts say that it should. Can you post the code of the complete form_alter function?
Note that you can also hide the revision information with the correct settings; it will only show if the "Create new revision" option is checked, or if the current user has the "administer nodes" permission.

Comment: Have you tried unsetting the whole revision information element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [marcvangend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241546/marcvangend)

> Note that you can also hide the
>   revision information with the correct
>   settings; it will only show if the
>   "Create new revision" option is
>   checked, or if the current user has
>   the "administer nodes" permission

This would probably be the easiest option.

*Note: wiki answer as it is not my own*

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Below code added by tejas tank , tta@openerp.com 
   to disable the revision block from everywhere    
*/
function phptemplate_node_form($form) {
    $form['revision_information']['#access'] = FALSE;
    return theme_node_form($form);
}
```